# C# - DataGridView - having unique CellClick events based on content

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have a design question about what the best approach is when you want to have different actions happen when a user clicks on a cell in a DataGridView, based on what type of information is in that cell.

Imagine the following scenario. There is a package delivery system and one of the screens shows a list of all deliveries currently scheduled. Columns could include:

- Delivery Number
- Customer Number
- Customer Delivery Location
- Primary Contact
- Delivery Order Receipt

If the user would click on a cell the action should be different based on what the column is. For example, if the user clicks on “Customer Delivery Location” it might open up a Delivery Location window which allows them to view/edit location details. If the user clicks on “Delivery Order Receipt” it might open a PDF window showing the receipt for the order.

The simple way to do this would be to do an If statement on the CellClick event. Pseudo code:

```
If (column = Delivery Order Receipt)
{
    LoadPDF()
} 
Else if (column = Customer Delivery Location)
{
    LaunchDeliveryWindow()
}
```

This seems a little sloppy to me. Especially if at some point in time the program needs to be expanded to include unique rightclick actions, or something along those lines. Then the code would basically have to be duplicated. Is there a better approach? What about having a class, maybe ColumnActionType, that defines what actions should be associated with a column?

Comment: I suppose it depends a lot on how many choices exist.  If left-clicking the `Delivery Order Receipt` column only produces one action, and other reactions are similarly 1:1, then your approach is not a bad one.  You could encapsulate it in a class, but at some point, you still have to decide what was clicked, how, and what to do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, below is decent way of implementing it. Especially if there aren't very many columns/actions. However it really depends on the situation as DonBoitnott pointed out in his comment.

```
private enum ActionType
{
    CellRightClick,
    CellDoubleClick
    // add as you need them
}    

private void dgv_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn selectedColumn = this.dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].OwningColumn;
        this.PerformActionOnColumn(ActionType.CellDoubleClick, selectedColumn.Name);
    }
}

private void PerformActionOnColumn(ActionType action, string columnName)
{
    switch (columnName)
    {
        case "col_One":
            switch (action)
            {
                case ActionType.CellRightClick:
                    // right click actions for col_One
                    break;

                case ActionType.CellDoubleClick:
                    // double click actions for col_One
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case "col_Two":
            switch (action)
            {
                case ActionType.CellRightClick:
                    // right click actions for col_Two
                    break;

                case ActionType.CellDoubleClick:
                    // double click actions for col_Two
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Where `dgv` is the `DataGridView` at hand. I put this in the `CellDoubleClick` event, but you can put it in any event that uses the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`, or really any event where you can access the currently selected column.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    private void dgGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (e.ColumnIndex == dgGridView.Columns["dgcCustomer"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
>         {
>             DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
>             .
>     .
>     .
>         }
>     }
> ```

Where dgGridView is the DataGridView object, "dgcCustomer" is a column in the DataGridView, and the dotted continuation lines is the response to that click event.

Answer (score -1):

I think using the switch statement would be better

```
switch (column) {
   case "Delivery Order Receipt":
      LoadPDF();
      break;
   case "Customer Delivery Location":
      LaunchDeliveryWindow();
      break;
   default:
      break;
   }
```

Comment: The question doesn't concern logical mechanics, rather design principles.